# Is there an airflow trigger rule for only success or failure or skipped? (i.e. run if anything except upstream_failure detected)

Tags: airflow, airflow-taskflow

I have quite a complicate DAG structure in airflow, and I am trying to set the trigger rule for a particular DAG where I would like it to run ONLY if the upstream of that DAG 'succeeded' or 'failed' or 'skipped'.

In short, I do not want it to run if 'upstream_failed' was detected.

Is there such a trigger rule to do this?

Thank you!

Or alternatively, is it possible to mark downstream tasks as 'skipped' if a task fails?